# Missing WCF tools in Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio, wcf, visual-studio-2013

Oke so recently i had the idea to pick up C# programming after my php,jquery studies etc. So what better way to learn it then just start programming. I am following some tutorial from the microsoft virtual academy and installed Visual Studio Express 2013 for Desktop, Visual Studio Express 2013 for Web and Visual Studio Express 2013 for Windows. These are all downloaded from the microsoft website and are regular (free editions)versions.

In the tutorial they are however creating an azure/web services project. In the new project in Visual Studio they creating a project with the tool WCF Service Library. Though, in my VS edition (all 3 of them) i don't have this tool (as well as the other WCF tools - WCF Service Application - WCF Workflow Service Application and Syndication Service Library). They are divided under the office / sharepoint tool.

So i read up a bit (on stack as well) and found out i had to download the 'Microsoft Office Developer Tools for Visual Studio', so i did. Though, to download this i am needing the Professional version of Visual Studio.

A few question however remain:

1. Are these tools missing because i don't have the office developer tools addon installed, is this correct?
2. And is there another way, in which i don't have to pay for something to get the WCF tools?

Perhaps i am tackling this in a entire wrong way, if you have any tips to just start programming then please share them:) Sorry for the perhaps nooby questions, just trying to learn it.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: The WCF Service Application should be available in 2013 for Web.  It doesn't appear that the WCF Service Library project is, but all that is a class library that contains the service contract and implementation, and is then hosted in your hosting scenario of choice.  You can create it by creating a class library and adding the appropriate references to it.

Comment: Download Visual Studio 2013 Community. It should be complete, free of charges.